# Phusion Passenger and Node.js

Tags: node.js, passenger

Is it possible to use Phusion Passenger with Node.js? If so how do I set it up to work with Node.js? Their documentation mentions nothing about Node.js but the tagline on their homepage says there is support for Node.js.

Comment: marketing strategy? :)

Comment: which way? do you want Phusion to serve the node responses or the other way around?

Comment: @TheHippo I have an express app that communicates with a sql server db and wanted to create multiple instances of the app without wasting money by using services like heroku.

Comment: @camelCaseD That was not my question. Okay, node.js/express <--> db, I get that. Why do you need Phusion Passanger at all? Node could run on it's own or gets an nginx frontend. Everything else does not make sense, as far as I understand your problem.

Comment: @TheHippo I share the same opinion, but still, as he mentions in the question, "Their documentation mentions nothing about Node.js but the tagline on their homepage says there is support for Node.js."

Comment: @TheHippo It just look like an easier way to get multiple instances setup as I've used it before for rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm one of the Phusion Passenger authors.

There is experimental support for Node.js (and Meteor!) in Phusion Passenger Enterprise 4. We're currently putting most of our focus on polishing the 4.0 release, meaning that we're doing mostly bug fixing and stability enhancing work. Once 4.0 is released we'll focus on features again, including Node.js and Meteor support.

**Update:** Node.js and Meteor support are released, and are now open source!

- [Phusion Passenger + Node.js tutorial](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial)
- [Phusion Passenger + Meteor tutorial](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/11/01/will-meteor-kill-rails-i-dont-know-but-phusion-passenger-open-sources-meteor-support/)

Comment: that's great to hear. While I wait for that though i'll find a temporary solution until support is added.

Comment: Is it possible to run with Phusion passenger multiple meteor apps where each app needs different version of node ?